# how to flow text around images that are in two columns?

Tags: css, image

I'm attempting to have text flow around images in the following fashion:
[image: desired-layout.jpg]

eg, images in two columns, with one image in the "center" column and a number of them in the right column.  I tried "floating boxes" via display:inline-block; and I tried a table-like config using display:table/display:table-cell, but I was unable to provide the correct (changing) width for the text on the left.

(The apparent alignment of the 2nd parag of text with the bottom of the center image is not necessary.)

Appreciation for your assistance!

Comment: Just use `float: right` on the large image...?

Comment: Have you tried using Bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @DiegoRosales Bootstap is an overkill for this.  Terry correctly mentioned `float: right` and that's all it needs.

Comment: @Simon You are right, might have tried some options before loading an entire library in there.

Comment: I had tried `float: right;`, but got unsatisfactory results - I didn't how to use/didn't grasp `clear:`  Thx to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a demo using `float` - does this accomplish what you want?

```css
.column {
  float: right;
}

.column img {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
</div>

<div class="column">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur et velit laoreet, volutpat urna venenatis, porttitor ligula. Ut nulla ipsum, pulvinar et metus sed, luctus volutpat velit. Nam consectetur diam eget dui rutrum imperdiet. Sed ornare tempor
  lorem. Cras sed neque fermentum, porttitor tortor eget, efficitur ligula. Maecenas laoreet dignissim arcu vitae semper. Suspendisse ac elementum ipsum, eu convallis urna. Etiam interdum, leo et molestie aliquam, turpis augue mattis neque, a pharetra
  diam orci nec augue. Aliquam id nisl a massa rhoncus mollis. Suspendisse et ex sit amet mi consequat efficitur. Nulla at turpis nec ante eleifend consequat. Nulla in molestie magna.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur et velit laoreet, volutpat urna venenatis, porttitor ligula. Ut nulla ipsum, pulvinar et metus sed, luctus volutpat velit. Nam consectetur diam eget dui rutrum imperdiet. Sed ornare tempor
  lorem. Cras sed neque fermentum, porttitor tortor eget, efficitur ligula. Maecenas laoreet dignissim arcu vitae semper. Suspendisse ac elementum ipsum, eu convallis urna. Etiam interdum, leo et molestie aliquam, turpis augue mattis neque, a pharetra
  diam orci nec augue. Aliquam id nisl a massa rhoncus mollis. Suspendisse et ex sit amet mi consequat efficitur. Nulla at turpis nec ante eleifend consequat. Nulla in molestie magna.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur et velit laoreet, volutpat urna venenatis, porttitor ligula. Ut nulla ipsum, pulvinar et metus sed, luctus volutpat velit. Nam consectetur diam eget dui rutrum imperdiet. Sed ornare tempor
  lorem. Cras sed neque fermentum, porttitor tortor eget, efficitur ligula. Maecenas laoreet dignissim arcu vitae semper. Suspendisse ac elementum ipsum, eu convallis urna. Etiam interdum, leo et molestie aliquam, turpis augue mattis neque, a pharetra
  diam orci nec augue. Aliquam id nisl a massa rhoncus mollis. Suspendisse et ex sit amet mi consequat efficitur. Nulla at turpis nec ante eleifend consequat. Nulla in molestie magna.</p>
```

Comment: Tnx for giving a code snippet, works perfectly - I didn't know how to use `clear`.  Question: why are two declarations for `.column` necessary?  Why does this single specification fail? 
`.column  {       
           float: right;
           clear: both
}`

Comment: @murspieg The second declaration is on the images inside the column, not the column. They're being "cleared" so they remain inside their specific column instead of spilling over.